# Function "SendMessage" of User32.dll does not work in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

I am developing a piece of software to extract some information from a external desktop application, the thing is that i am working in Windows 7 using C# and I have got a workable application that uses the stuff of here:

[How can I retrieve the values from window of class "ThunderRT6ListBox" using user32.dll in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880330/how-can-i-retrieve-the-values-from-window-of-class-thunderrt6listbox-using-use/)

But the problem comes when I test the same software against the same external application in Windows 8, it doesn't work in the same way.

I can copy the handler id of the controls but when I use the SendMessage function, for example, to put a new text to a edit control (textbox), nothing is happened.

```
    public static void SetText(IntPtr HWnd, string strTextToSet)
    {
        var text = new StringBuilder(strTextToSet);
        SendMessage(HWnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, text);
    }
```

Is there any consideration in Windows 8 when it used this stuff?

UPDATE:

Still it does not work. GetText works, but SetText doesn't.

My code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]        
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

    public static string GetText(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var text = new StringBuilder(1024);
        if (SendMessageTimeoutText(hwnd, 0xd, 1024, text, 0x2, 1000, 0) != 0)
        {
            return text.ToString();
        }

        return "";
    }

    public static void SetText(IntPtr HWnd, string strTextToSet)
    {
        //var text = new StringBuilder(strTextToSet);
        IntPtr text = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(strTextToSet);
        SendMessage(HWnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, text);
    }
```

UPDATE 2:

Error code:

```
    ModApi.SetText(hwEdit, "foo_namE");

    //The textbox does not change

    int error_code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    //error_code is 5
```

Comment: What's the result of `GetLastError` after the "nothing happens" part?

Comment: This was a better response than mine; best to id the problem than just tear it all down and put in a new solution as I did in my answer below.

Comment: @Jcl You cannot call `GetLastError`. You have to use `SetLastError` in the pinvoke and then call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`.

Comment: Please show the pinvoke. Please tells us how you obtain the window handle. Please tell us which window you are poking at. Please tell us the return value of `SendMessage`. Please let us know how we can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I was not trying to give a solution to the problem, was just trying to get the original poster to investigate further than "nothing happens". Guess it didn't work :-) (and yes, you are indeed right)

Comment: Ok, i update the information about the error code. Its value is 5.

Comment: @videador if you check [MSDN documentation on SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) you'll see this: _When a message is blocked by UIPI the last error, retrieved with GetLastError, is set to 5 (access denied)._

Comment: meaning: there's a problem with privileges, probably a matter of UAC... try running your process elevated (that is: _run as admin_)

Comment: That was the solution, thanks Jcl.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the about UAC (User Access Control), I needed to launch Visual Studio in administration mode (or the executable when it will be built).

Comment: Only because the other app runs elevated

Comment: And how could wm_get text work? That's implausible unless you were sending to a different process from wm_wettest target.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, my tablet decided it could spell better than I could. My point is that if UAC blocks WM_SETTEXT then it will also block WM_GETTEXT. So were both messages really going to the same window?

Answer (score 0):

Per this ([SendMessage WM_SETTEXT to TextBox doesn't trigger TextChanged Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634120/sendmessage-wm-settext-to-textbox-doesnt-trigger-textchanged-event)) other question on SO, the following works on my system in a Windows 8 forms application:

```
//Declarations
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;


//SetText function
        public static void SetText(IntPtr HWnd, string strTextToSet)
        {
            IntPtr text = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(strTextToSet);
            SendMessage(HWnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, text);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(text);

        }
```

Comment: Nothing but the moment, I've updated the code with your changes (the param lParam), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You meant `CharSet.Auto` since you called `StringToCoTaskMemUni`

Comment: David, I'm not following your reference to where the code should change?  I'm setting the Charset to CharSet.Auto on the declaration attribute - I'm not seeing anywhere else I need to change it.  Thanks!

Comment: Videador - For the sake of clarity, what type of an application are you building?  Is it a Windows Forms application, and if so, what platform are you targeting (x86, x64), and for the fun of it, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @JayTaplin typed the wrong thing. Should have said CharSet.Unicode. Sorry. I'd also like you to explain why your code would fix anything.

Comment: Jay, I am working with Visual Studio Express 10 c#, framework NET 4.0 (About platform I suppose x86 but i don't know). I am going with the SeeLastError issue, thanks David.

Comment: David - thanks for the feedback on my answer.  In regards to why my code would "fix" anything, it was written before update #2 and #3 were added to the question, so there was little to go on regarding the environment in which the code was failing.  This is why I acknowledged above that finding the root cause would be much smarter than just using my answer.  However, prior to that I provided code that worked on my system based on the question I linked to at the top of my answer.

Comment: The original code in the question works on your system too. There is nothing to go on here. Adding an answer like this doesn't really help. What is needed is for the asker to spend time making a repro case. Having the asker spending time trying to make multiple variations of the pinvoke that all do the same thing just diverts from the real task. Anyway, it's down to videaor to make a repro. Otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your feedback David.  I'm new to trying to answer questions on this site, so I appreciate the information about process and procedure.